# Passenger has modified NODE_PATH which my app uses during startup

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, phusion-passenger

I'm implementing Passenger, on an Apache server (a Digital Ocean droplet, running Ubuntu 16.04), with a Node.js app. Webpack successfully builds the static .js file, and Node successfully runs the startup. However, when accessing the site from a browser, I get errors like `Cannot find module 'app/path/to/file'`.
My app uses the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to set the app source to `./src` so in import statements I don't have to set the path as `src/app/path/to/file`, rather just `app/path/to/file`. However, Passenger is modifying the `NODE_PATH` variable, and when making a request to render the page, Node crashes Passenger because `NODE_PATH` is no longer set to `./src` (however, during Node startup and Webpack build, `NODE_PATH=./src` because Passenger is not involved in these processes).

So my question is, what is an alternative to setting `NODE_PATH=./src` but still keeping the same effects (i.e `src/app/path/to/file` => `app/path/to/file`).

Comment: Don't use NODE_PATH. It's deprecated since node 0.10. Use symlinks for example